# Definite integral of modified bessel functions of the first kind and trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I have the following definite integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} cos(n\theta)[I_{1}(acos\theta) + cos\theta I_{0}(acos\theta)]d\theta
$$

with $I_{1}$ and $I_{0}$ the first and zero-order modified bessel functions of the first kind respectively ; $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}^{+*}$.

with the hint that,

$$
I_{n}(z) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{zcos\theta}cos(n\theta)d\theta
$$

we can transform the previous integral,

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} cos(\theta)I_{n}(acos\theta) + \frac{1}{2}(I_{n+1}(acos\theta) + I_{n-1}(acos\theta))d\theta
$$
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} cos(\theta)I_{n}(acos\theta) - \frac{1}{asin\theta}(I_{n}^{'}(acos\theta))d\theta
$$

I couldn't go any further in the computation. But using the power series representation and considering $n$ odd and $n=2m+1$, we obtain:

$$
\pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{U^{2k+n-1}}{2^{2k+n}\Gamma (k+n+1) k!} \prod_{i=1}^{k+m} (\frac{2i-1}{2i}) (U\frac{2(k+m)+1}{2(k+m+1)} + 2k+n) 
$$

If someone has an idea ... Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you're trying to find the cosine transform of $I_{1}(a\cos\theta) + I_{0}(a\cos\theta)\cos\theta$, then?

Comment: Yes, actually, it can be written as the integral of $cos(n\theta)(I_{1}(acos\theta) + I_{0}(acos\theta)cos\theta)d\theta$.

Comment: Do you *really* need the indefinite integral? The definite integral over $(-1,1)$ asks for the Fourier-Chebyshev series of $I_1(x)$, i.e. for the Fourier series of $I_1(\cos x)$, that is straightforward given the definition of $I_1$ as a coefficient of a Fourier series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You are right, if I understand it well, we can consider the $2\pi$-periodic function $s(\theta) = I_{1}(acos\theta) + I_{0}(acos\theta)cos\theta$ and the definite integral $a_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}cos(n\theta)s(\theta)$ is a coefficient of a Fourier series. But how can I evaluate this coefficient ?

Comment: @LA.Dufrene: $$I_n(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{z\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)\,d\theta$$ is the key relation, if your problem deals with the integral over $(-1,1)$. Is it so?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: After checking my problem, yes, the integral of the original post (with variable x) can also be defined on $(-1,1)$ or equivalently on $(0,\pi)$ with variable $\theta$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thanks Jack, but I still don't understand how to use this relation to solve my problem.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thanks Jack for your help, but I couldn't find the answer, so I'm giving up now. I'll try to find a Maple license. Eventually, if I find the answer I will post it in comment.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Jack you seemed to know the answer, could you confirm the edit and eventually giving me another hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the integral

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} cos(\theta) I_{n}(acos(\theta)) + \frac{1}{2}(I_{n+1}(acos(\theta)) + I_{n-1}(acos(\theta))) d\theta
$$

and apply the solution of the integral [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=aBgFYxKHUjsC&pg=PR10&lpg=PR10&dq=trigonometric+function+bessel+function&source=bl&ots=bLlzUYA9NC&sig=HtU0G5uom2w-8z4Ux4Hm_Xd-XVg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil7Ifk6KPSAhWEVRQKHZVNC3M4ChDoAQg6MAU#v=onepage&q=trigonometric%20function%20bessel%20function&f=false), p724, 6.681-3:

$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} cos(2\mu x)I_{2\nu}(2acosx)dx = \frac{\pi}{2}I_{\nu-\mu}(a)I_{\nu+\mu}(a)
$$

This is also valid for the sinus by symmetry in our case. Stating $n=2m+1$ we obtain,

$$
\pi I_{m}(\frac{a}{2})I_{m+1}(\frac{a}{2}) + \frac{\pi}{2}I_{m+1}(\frac{a}{2})^{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}I_{m}(\frac{a}{2})^{2}
$$